# Using JSON to create a schema that stores permissible values and dates/times. Does my approach make sense?

Tags: json, key, schema

I have live music event data that I would like to store in JSON. I have never used the schema before so I have some questions about the JSON schema and my specific approach.

Suppose a live music event is associated with the following data:

`╔═════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ Event ID            ║ 00001                          ║
║ Event Name          ║ Rock and Roll Jam              ║
║ Artist ID           ║ 001240                         ║
║ Venue ID            ║ 00422                          ║
║ Event URL           ║ www.livemusic.com/randrjam     ║
║ Event Twitter       ║ @randrjam                      ║
║ Event Genre         ║ Rock / Alternative             ║
║ Event Details ID    ║ 001                            ║
║ Event Details Date  ║ Mar 31 2014                    ║
║ Event Details Time  ║ 7 PM - 10 PM                   ║
║ Event Details Price ║ $5                             ║
║ Event Details ID    ║ 002                            ║
║ Event Details Date  ║ April 1 2014                   ║
║ Event Details Time  ║ 8 PM - 11 PM                   ║
║ Event Details Price ║ $10                            ║
╚═════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝`

I have chosen to structure this event data using the following JSON schema:

```
   {
“event”:”object”,
“properties”:{
    "eventID”:{
        “type”:”number”,
        “required”:true
    },
    "eventName”:{
        “type”:”string”,
        “required”:true
    },
    "ArtistID”:{
        “type”:”number”,
        “required”:true
    },
    "venueID”:{
        “type”:”number”,
        “required”:true
    },
    "eventURL”:{
        “type”:”string”,
        “required”:false
    },
    "eventTwitter”:{
        “type”:”string”,
        “required”:false
    },
    "eventGenre”:{
        “type”:”string”,
        “required”:false
    },
    “eventDetails”:”object”,
    “properties”:{
        "eventDetailsID”:{
            “type”:”number”,
            “required”:true
        },
        "eventDate”:{
            “type”:”number”,
            “required”:true
        },
        "eventStartTime”:{
            “type”:”number”,
            “required”:false
        },
        "eventEndTime”:{
            “type”:”number”,
            “required”:false
        },
        "eventPrice”:{
            “type”:”number”,
            “required”:false
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have three questions about my schema.

1. For the event genre key, I have a list of permissible values (of which rock and country are only two). Is there a way to store the permissible values with the schema so that it is evident what values are permissible for specific keys?
2. I have decided to store dates and times with UNIX timestamps since there doesn't seem to be a native date or time data type in JSON. Does that make sense?
3. Is my JSON valid? What would be the best way to automatically validate it?

As I mentioned above, I am new to the schema so please let me know if something doesn't make sense and requires clarification.

Comment: I found this validator - http://jsonlint.com/ - and it says my JSON is not valid but I am still trying to figure out the error message. It looks like my third question has been answered.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. I was using curly quotes when the parser only wants straight quotes.